# atigktxx.dll in wxWidgets: "Access violation reading location 0xFEEEFEEE" (Release build)

Tags: c++, windows, wxwidgets

I get the occasional access violation when I start my wxwidget application:

```
Unhandled exception at 0x0267894A (atigktxx.dll) in MyApp.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xFEEEFEEE.
```

This is strange since is happens when I start the Release build. Shouldn't `0XFEEEFEEE` point to uninitialized memory in Debug mode?

I usually get rid of the error by rebuilding my project (only).
So there's not really a chance to reproduce the error.

Has anyone come across this? I use wxGLCanvas widgets in my programm.

Comment: *I usually get rid of the error by rebuilding my project* -- That would not be considered a fix of the issue.  Second, you can debug the release builds by turning on the debug options in your (assuming) Visual C++ project settings for the release build.

Comment: are you sure you aren't using the same "intermediate directory" for both your debug and release builds? that could cause some debug *.obj files being linked into your release build

Answer (score 1):

The first thing to do is to find out where exactly this access violation happens and you should be able to do this by choosing to break at Win32 exceptions when you run the program under debugger.

If it happens deep inside ATI OpenGL driver, it would seem to indicate yet another weirdness in ATI code and it wouldn't be the first one, e.g. it's also [known](http://wxwidgets.blogspot.com/2014/07/invalid-parameter-debug-messages-when.html) to call CRT functions with invalid parameters.

OTOH it's also possible that you really pass an invalid parameter to some OpenGL function and in this case the stack backtrace should give at least some information about which function and which parameter it is.